# Why does reading an integer from standard input trigger an invalid input?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to receive a input which is exclusivily an Integer, so I tried this:

```
use std::io;

fn main(){
    println!("Guess the Number!");
    println!("Enter with a number: ");

    let mut guess = String::new();

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess).expect("Failed");

    match guess.parse::<u8>(){
        Ok(i) =>  println!("Your number is {}",guess),
        Err(..) => println!("Invalid input"),
    };
   
}
```

But no matter if I enter with a integer, trigger an invalid input

```
Guess the Number!
Enter with a number: 
12
Invalid input
```

Comment: `guess.trim().parse::<u8>()`. I encourage you to re-read [Programming a Guessing Game](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html)

Comment: I did it, but even so I receive an invalid input getting with integer

Comment: I copied the code provided here, changed the line as shown in my previous comment, ran the program, entered `12` as your example shows, and it worked. You will need to double check your setup; perhaps you forgot to save the file or recompile it?

Comment: Yeap man, my bad! Its works! Thanks and I will re read the link